# how to get proper indian currency format for price in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, currency

in magento front end its showing ₹7,765,000.00

But we need  ₹77,65,000.00

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); // Instance of Object Manager
    $priceHelper = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data'); // Instance of Pricing Helper
    $price =  43200000; //Your Price
   echo $formattedPrice = $priceHelper->currency($price, true, false);
```

it should display ₹4,32,00000
but it it displaying ₹43,200,000.00

Comment: do you have multi currency ?

Comment: no,i dont have.

Answer (score 2):

**Option I**

At the moment you setup Rupee as currency, but it is taking format as per `Locale` you set in admin.

If you want format as per Indian currency, you need to change your `Locale` to `Hindi (India)`.

**Option II**

If you don't want to change `Locale`, You need to change `currencyFormat`.

You can find file at:

> vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Locale/Data

1. Select file as per your `Locale`
2. Search for `<currencyFormat`
3. Change format.

**Note** If you are going with Option II, you need a proper override. **Never** edit core file

Comment: i choose option 1. its working in listing page. but not in product page

Comment: Yes, I checked on PDP initial it is showing correct format price, then it is changing! let me check solution.